# Seleccionar campo con javascript (no value)

Tags: javascript, html

Buenas a todos quisiera que al cargar una página con su formulario, un campo de texto determinado esté seleccionado sin necesidad de hacer clic en él, esto con el fin de tratar al máximo de evitar hacer uso del mouse, he googleado pero en todos lados sale el típico document.getElementByID.value() y ese es para seleccionar el valor, yo solo quiero selecionar el campo al cargar la página, como si hicieramos clic en él, muchas gracias

Answer (score 3):

Tenés que usar la función .focus()

```
document.getElementById("mytext").focus();
```

Answer (score 1):

Propiedad `autofocus` del la etiqueta `input`

```
<form action="/action_page.php">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname" autofocus><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

[HTML Input autofocus Attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autofocus.asp)